# Prove a sum is not an integer

Tags: number-theory

I am working on a problem.

Consider the set S of integers $1,2,...,n$. Let $2^k$ be the integer in S that is the highest power of $2$. Prove that $2^k$ is not a divisor of any other integer in S. Hence prove that $ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j}$ is not an integer if $n>1$.

I turned out with the first one, but still got stuck to prove the sum is not an integer. I don't know how to use the first part to prove the second part.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the numbers from $1$ to $n$ can be written in the form $m2^s,$ where $m$ is odd.  By definition of $k, s \le k$ in every case, and in all but one case, $s \le k-1.$ Now, suppose the sum is equal to an integer, and multiply both sides by $2^{k-1}.$  One of the terms in the equation is a fraction with an even denominator, and all the rest have odd denominators.  Deduce a contraction.

Comment: The second part need to use the first part to prove it. So I think there will be another way to prove. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  I have used the first part when I said that all but one of the fractions has odd denominator.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see when you said that you used the fact the $2^k$ is not a divisor of any other integer in your claim.

Comment: I added more explanation.  I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: If it solves your problem, you ought to accept it by clicking on the check mark, so other users will know your question's been dealt with.